# Выходит ошибка: Exception ImportError: cannot import name validate_is_mapping. Версия python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, pymongo

```
Exception ImportError: cannot import name validate_is_mapping
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/emartynchuk/.local/bin/behave", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/emartynchuk/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/behave/__main__.py", line 183, in main
    return run_behave(config)
  File "/home/emartynchuk/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/behave/__main__.py", line 127, in run_behave
    failed = runner.run()
  File "/home/emartynchuk/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/behave/runner.py", line 804, in run
    return self.run_with_paths()
  File "/home/emartynchuk/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/behave/runner.py", line 809, in run_with_paths
    self.load_step_definitions()
  File "/home/emartynchuk/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/behave/runner.py", line 796, in load_step_definitions
    load_step_modules(step_paths)
  File "/home/emartynchuk/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/behave/runner_util.py", line 412, in load_step_modules
    exec_file(os.path.join(path, name), step_module_globals)
  File "/home/emartynchuk/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/behave/runner_util.py", line 386, in exec_file
    exec(code, globals_, locals_)
  File "steps/step_cancel_request_payment.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pymongo.operations import UpdateMany
  File "/home/emartynchuk/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/operations.py", line 17, in <module>
    from pymongo.common import validate_boolean, validate_is_mapping, validate_list
ImportError: cannot import name validate_is_mapping
```

Comment: А модуль "validate_is_mapping" вы поставили?

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как поставить модуль.

Comment: `from pymongo.common import validate_boolean, validate_is_mapping, validate_list ` - нужен модуль pymongo.common, возможно это поможет: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26218990/how-to-install-pymongo